# NativeAppInstallAd and PublisherAdView mixed in Android app

Tags: android, google-dfp, admob

I'm working on an app that currently shows ads from AdMob (using mediation and CustomEventBanners) using `PublisherAdView`

The app is also able to show `NativeAppInstallAd`'s and I got that to work.

My customer handles the showing of the corresponding apps by setting them in DFP. This way he can determine what ad needs to be shown and this works for banners.

But he wants to be able to show `NativeAppInstallAd`'s and `Banners` on the same position and handle which one will be shown managed from DFP.

I'm unable to find anything about this. Is this possible in any way? Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm willing to write something custom for this if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that this is actually possible using `AdLoader`.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/AdLoader.Builder#forPublisherAdView(com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.OnPublisherAdViewLoadedListener, com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize...)